# Stop PHP from auto generating values

Tags: php, mysql, auto, generate

I am new in php. I have a PHP script which auto generates a tracking number in mysql database `cons_no` is the name of the table, I wish to enter the `cons_no` data manually.

Also when I try to edit the `cons_no` value from the edit page, other things are allowed to be edited - except `con_no`. Any help will be appreciated. 
This is the code that creates the the file with the `cons_no` value.

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
session_start();
//Include database configuration file
require_once('database-settings.php');
require_once('database.php');
$db = conexion();

require_once('library.php');
require_once('funciones.php');
require 'requirelanguage.php';
include_once "filtro/class/class.php";;
include_once "filtro/class_buscar.php";
require_once("filtro/class/class.inputfilter.php");
$ifilter = new InputFilter();
$_POST = $ifilter->process($_POST);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(off_name)
        FROM offices";
$result = dbQuery($sql);

$company=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company"));
date_default_timezone_set($_SESSION['ge_timezone']);
$fechai=date('Y-m-d');
$fechaf=date('Y-m-d');

isUser();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_cname']; ?> | <?php echo $ENVIOS; ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_description']; ?>"/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_keywords']; ?>" />
    <meta name="author" content="Jaomweb">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Switchery css -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/switchery/switchery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!-- Plugins css -->
    <link href="assets/plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/plugins/mjolnic-bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/plugins/clockpicker/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/plugins/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<?php
include("header.php");
?>

  <!-- content -->
  <div id="content" class="app-content" role="main">
    <div class="app-content-body ">

<div class="wrapper-md">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="blog-post">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="wrapper-lg">
                <div>
                    <tbody>
                        <div class="row alertaCaja" style="display: none;">
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert danger">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><img src="img/close.png"  height="15" width="15"></button>
                                        <center>
                                            <?php   
                                            require_once('database.php');
                                            $query= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cid) AS id FROM courier");
                                             if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) 
                                             {

                                            ?> 
                                                <a target="_blank" href="print-invoice/invoice-print.php?cid=<?php echo codificar($id = trim($row[0])); ?>">
                                                <img src="img/print-invoice.png"  height="76" width="79"></a>
                                            <?php } ?>

                                            <?php   
                                            require_once('database.php');
                                            $query= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cid) AS id FROM courier");
                                             if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) 
                                             {

                                            ?> 
                                                <a target="_blank" href="print-invoice/ticket-print.php?cid=<?php echo codificar($id = trim($row[0])); ?>">
                                                <img src="img/print_label.png"  height="76" width="79"></a>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php   if ( isset ( $_GET ['tipo'] ) ) {   ?>                  
                        <div class="row alertaCaja" style="display: none;" >
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-<?php echo $_GET ['tipo'] ?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                                    <strong><?php echo $L_['message']; ?></strong><br/><br/> <?php echo $_GET ['mensaje']; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <tr>
                        <h3 class="classic-title"><span><strong><i class="fa fa-truck icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $ADICIONAR; ?></strong></h3>

                        <!-- START Checkout form -->

                        <form action="settings/add_courier/agregar.php"   method="post" >
                            <table border="0" align="center" width="100%" >
                                <div class="row">

                                        <!-- START Presonal information -->
                                        <fieldset class="col-md-6">
                                            <legend><?php echo $datosremite; ?></legend>
                                            <!-- Name -->
                                            <div class="row" >
                                                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                                        <label  class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-user icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $StaffRole; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="officename" id="officename" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_type'] ;?>"   readonly="true" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                                                        <label  class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-user icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $StaffUser; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name'] ;?>"   readonly="true" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">

                                                    <label class="control-label" ><?php echo $NOMBREREMITENTE; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Shippername"  id="Shippername" autocomplete="on" list="customers" />
                                                       <datalist id="customers">
                                                        <?php
                                                            $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_clients");
                                                            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                                                                echo '<option data-value="'.$row['id'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['name']).'</option>';
                                                            }
                                                        ?>
                                                      </datalist>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="Shippername-hidden" id="Shippername-hidden" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div id="divRemi">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                                        <label  class="control-label"><?php echo $DIRECCION; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                        <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="Shipperaddress" id="Shipperaddress" placeholder="<?php echo $placeremi; ?>" />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label  class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-phone icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $TELEFONO; ?></label>
                                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="Shipperphone" id="Shipperphone" placeholder="<?php echo $placetele; ?>" />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $CEDULA; ?></i></label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Shippercc" id="Shippercc"  placeholder="<?php echo $placeced; ?>" >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group" style="display:none">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $L_['lockerid']; ?></i></label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Shipperlocker" id="Shipperlocker"  placeholder="<?php echo $L_['lockerid']; ?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<strong><?php echo $PAISORIGEN; ?></strong></label>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Pickuptime" id="Shippercountry" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placecountry']; ?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $L_STATE; ?></strong></label>
                                                            <input  type="text"  class="form-control" name="state"  id="Shipperstate"  placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placestate']; ?>">                                                              
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group" style="display:none">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CODIGO; ?></strong></label>
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iso" id="Shipperiso" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placeiso']; ?>" >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CIUDAD; ?></strong></label>
                                                            <input  type="text"   class="form-control" id="Shipperciudad" name="ciudad"  placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placecity']; ?>" >
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CODIGOPOSTAL; ?></strong></label>
                                                            <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="Shipperzipcode" name="zipcode"  placeholder="<?php echo $codigopostal; ?>">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                                        <p class="error"></p>
                                                        <label class="control-label"><?php echo $EMAIL; ?><font color="#FF6100"><?php echo $notaemail; ?></font></i></label>
                                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Shipperemail" id="idemail"   placeholder="demo@emo.com" autocomplete=" off" onKeyUp="javascript:validateeMail('idemail')" />
                                                        <strong><span id="mailOK"></span></strong>
                                                        <p class="error"></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- Adress and Phone -->

                                            <!-- START Shipment information -->
                                            </br></br>
                                            <legend><?php echo $Informaciondeenvio; ?></legend>

                                            <div class="row">

                                            <!-- Origin Office -->

                                               <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                 <label for="zipcode" class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<strong><?php echo $OFICINAORIGEN; ?></strong></label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="Invoiceno">
                                                        <?php
                                                        while($data = dbFetchAssoc($result)){
                                                        ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $data['off_name']; ?>"><?php echo $data['off_name']; ?></option>
                                                        <?php
                                                        }//while
                                                        ?>
                                                   </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label for="ccv" class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CantidadPaquetes; ?></strong></i></label>
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Qnty"  placeholder="<?php echo $placecant; ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                                    <!-- Text area -->
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                                    <label for="inputTextarea" class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-comments icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $DetallesdelEnvio; ?></label>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="Comments" placeholder="<?php echo $placedetails; ?>" ></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-database icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<strong><?php echo $Pagos; ?></strong></label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="bookingmode">
                                                        <option selected="selected" value="Effective"><?php echo $Effective; ?></option>
                                                        <option value="Debit_card"><?php echo $Debitcard; ?></option>
                                                        <option value="Credit_card"><?php echo $Creditcard; ?></option>
                                                        <option value="Transfer"><?php echo $Transfer; ?></option>
                                                        <option value="Online"><?php echo $Payonline; ?></option>
                                                        <option value="Paypal"><?php echo $L_['type_paypal']; ?></option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $TipodeProducto; ?></label>
                                                    <select  type="text" class="form-control" name="Shiptype"  >
                                                        <?php
                                                            $sql="SELECT name FROM type_shipments  GROUP BY name"; 
                                                                $query=$db->query($sql); 
                                                                if($query->num_rows>0){ 
                                                                    while($row=$query->fetch_array()){ 
                                                                    echo '<option data-value="'.$row['name'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['name']).'</option>';
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-plane icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $MododelServicio; ?></label>
                                                  <select class="form-control" name="Mode">
                                                    <?php
                                                        $sql="SELECT name FROM mode_bookings  GROUP BY name"; 
                                                            $query=$db->query($sql); 
                                                            if($query->num_rows>0){ 
                                                                while($row=$query->fetch_array()){ 
                                                                echo '<option data-value="'.$row['name'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['name']).'</option>';
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    ?>
                                                  </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                             <!-- Payment Mode -->
                                             <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group" >
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_curr']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $ValorDeclarado; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum2"  name="Totaldeclarate"   value="0" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group" >
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $Declarado; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum5"  name="Totaldeclarado"  value="4" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label for="ccv" class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_curr']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $ValorRecogida; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();"  id="sum3" name="Totalfreight" value="0" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_curr']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $PrimerKilo; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_measure']; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum1"    name="variable" value="3.25" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_curr']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_measure']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $KiloAdicional; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="suma();" id="sum6" name="kiloadicional" value="3.25" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $PesoKg; ?>&nbsp;(<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_measure']; ?>)<strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="suma();"  id="sum4"   name="Weight" value="0" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $SubtotalEnvio; ?><strong></i></label>
                                                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="shipping_subtotal" id="resultado" value="0" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-danger"><strong><?php echo $_SESSION['ge_curr']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $PesoFisico; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="pesoreal" name="pesoreal" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" >
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <legend><?php echo $pesovolumetrico; ?>:</legend>

                                            <!-- Peso Volumetrico -->

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $Altura; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="volumetrico();" id="volume1"    name="altura" placeholder="<?php echo $Altura; ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $Ancho; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}"  onKeyUp="svolumetrico();" id="volume2"    name="ancho" placeholder="<?php echo $Ancho; ?>" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $Longitud; ?><strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='0'}" onKeyUp="volumetrico();" id="volume3"   name="longitud" placeholder="<?php echo $Longitud; ?>" />
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="text-primary"><strong><?php echo $TotalPesoVolumetrico; ?><strong></i></label>
                                                    <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="totalpeso" id="totalpeso" placeholder="0,00" />

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>

                                        <!-- START Receiver info  -->
                                        <fieldset class="col-md-6">
                                            <legend><?php echo $DatosDestinatario; ?></legend>

                                            <!-- Name -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label  class="control-label"><?php echo $NOMBREDESTINATARIO; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Receivername" id="Receivername" autocomplete="on" list="customers" >

                                            </div>


                                            <!-- Adress and Phone -->
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label  class="control-label"><?php echo $DIRECCION; ?><span class="required-field">*</span></label>
                                                    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="Receiveraddress" id="Receiveraddress" placeholder="<?php echo $placedirdesti; ?>" >
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label  class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-phone icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $TELEFONO; ?></label>
                                                    <input type="tel"  class="form-control" name="Receiverphone" id="Receiverphone" placeholder="<?php echo $placeteldesti; ?>" >
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label  class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-phone icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $TELEFONO2; ?></label>
                                                    <input type="tel"  class="form-control" name="telefono1" id="Receivertelefono1" placeholder="<?php echo $placeteldesti; ?>">
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $CEDULA; ?></i></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Receivercc_r" id="Receivercc_r" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placecedr']; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<strong><?php echo $PAISDESTINO; ?></strong></label>
                                                        <input  type="text"  class="form-control" name="paisdestino" id="Receivercountry1" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placecountry1']; ?>" >                                              
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $L_STATE; ?></strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state1" id="Receiverstate1" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placestate']; ?>" >

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group" style="display:none">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CODIGO; ?></strong></label>
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iso1"  id="Receiveriso1"  placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placeiso']; ?>" >
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CIUDAD; ?></strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city1"  id="Receivercity1" placeholder="<?php echo $L_['placecity']; ?>" >                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3 form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label"><strong><?php echo $CODIGOPOSTAL; ?></strong></label>
                                                        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode1" id="Receiverzipcode1" placeholder="<?php echo $codigopostal; ?>">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                                    <p class="error"></p>
                                                    <label class="control-label"><?php echo $EMAIL; ?><font color="#FF6100"><?php echo $notaemail; ?></font></i></label>
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Receiveremail" id="id_mail"   placeholder="demo@emo.com"  onKeyUp="javascript:validateMail('id_mail')" >
                                                    <strong><span id="emailOK"></span></strong>
                                                    <p class="error"></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </br></br>

                                            <!-- Name -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name-card" class="text-success"><strong><?php echo $NUMEROENVIO; ?></strong></label>
                                            <?php                                           
                                                $qryEmpresa =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM company");
                                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qryEmpresa)) {
                                                    $pre  = $row["prefijo"];
                                                    $cons  = $row["cons_no"];
                                                }
                                                mysql_free_result($qryEmpresa);
                                                $pa=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(cons_no)as maximo FROM c_tracking");                
                                                if($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
                                                    if($row['maximo']==NULL){
                                                        $cons_no=''.$cons.'';
                                                    }else{
                                                        $cons_no=$row['maximo']+1;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                            ?>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ge_prefix']; ?>-<?php echo "".$cons_no; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                            </br>

                                            <!-- Status and Pickup Date -->
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="dtp_input1" class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $FECHARECOLECCIONENVIO; ?></i></label>
                                                <div>
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Packupdate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker-autoclose" >
                                                        <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                                    </div><!-- input-group -->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                    <label for="month" class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $estado; ?></label>
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
                                                            <?php
                                                                $sql="SELECT servicemode FROM service_mode  GROUP BY servicemode"; 
                                                                $query=$db->query($sql); 
                                                                if($query->num_rows>0){ 
                                                                    while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
                                                                    echo '<option data-value="'.$row['servicemode'].'">'.utf8_encode($row['servicemode']).'</option>';

                                                                    }
                                                                }

                                                            ?>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-8 form-group">
                                                        <label for="dtp_input1" class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar icon text-default-lter"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $fechaestimadadeliver; ?></i></label>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <div class="input-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Schedule" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" id="datepicker">
                                                            <span class="input-group-addon bg-custom b-0"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                                        </div><!-- input-group -->
                                                    </div>

                                                    </fieldset>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                                                        </br></br>                                                      
                                                        <button type="submit"  id="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-success"><?php echo $GUARDARENVIO; ?></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </table>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / content -->

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>

<?php include("footer_add_courier.php"); ?>
```

Comment: `$row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)` is probably not what you intend for that conditional to be doing. `$row['maximo']` I'd guess will never be null so you are always adding 1.

Comment: @user3783243 Please can you be a bit more clear and elaborate. I don't get it, i just want the script to allow me enter the "cons_no" value manually, rather than generating automatically.

Comment: Please upgrade your functions from `mysql_` to `mysqli_`.  Your file was too long; didn't read.

Comment: (Why is there like 3 `require_once('database.php');`? Also, php tags seem to open and close randomly.) `$cons_no` takes value either from your `$row['maximo']` or `$row['cons_no']`. If you do not like them either delete the surrounding if (it doesn't do anything else) and give a value manually, or just simply overwrite it after the if (ehh, a bit idiot solution.)